# Visa requirement with a residence permit from Greece

Tags: turkish-citizens

I am of Turkish nationality and have a residence permit from Greece. If I fly from Turkey directly to Germany, do I need a visa?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Your residence permit from a Schengen country allows you to travel to other Schengen countries for up to 90 days in any 180-day period.  See [Travel Documents for non-EU Nationals](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm):

> If you have a valid residence permit from one of those Schengen countries, it is equivalent to a visa.